# Then $\{ f \in R\mid f(0) = f'(0) = 0 \}$ is choose the coorect option

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the ring $R = C^1[-1,1]$ of all continuously differentiable real
valued functions on $[−1, 1]$ with the usual operations of pointwise addition
and pointwise multiplication.

Then   $\{ f \in R\mid f(0) = f'(0) = 0 \}$ is

choose the coorect option

$1)$  subring

$2)$ Ideal

## My attempt  :

i know that definition of Subring : An nonempty subset $S$ of a Ring $R$ is subring if and only if

$1)$ $a-b \in S $

$2)$ $ab \in S $   for all $a,b \in S$

Definition of Ideal : An nonempty subset $S$ of a Ring $R$ is Ideal if and only if

$1)$ $a-b \in S $

$2)$ $ar \in S $   for $a \in S$ and $r \in R$

Now  From the  definition    i thinks   both option a) and b)  are correct

Pliz tell  me am i right  or wrong?

Comment: Every ideal is a subring. So if you have shown it is an ideal then by default it is a subring as well.

Comment: @AnuragA isn't part of the definition of a subring that it has to contain $1$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout A ring may not even have a multiplicative identity (depends on whom you follow: Fraenkel or Noether :-)), so that is not part of the definition of a subring. And even if ring has an identity, a subring may not have it, for example think of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If you're asked for *the* correct option, then it's 2, because the identity element of the ring $R$ doesn't belong to the given subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set described:
$$
    S = \left\{ f\in R \mid f(0) = f'(0) = 0 \right\}
$$

Two calculus facts seem relevant:

1. The sum rule: $(f+g)'(0) = f'(0) + g'(0)$
2. The product rule: $(fg)'(0) = f'(0) g(0) + f(0)g'(0)$.

So is it true that if $f\in S$ and $g\in S$ then $fg \in S$?  What about if $f\in S$ and $g \notin S$?

Comment: ,@ Mathhew ,,im not able to  find a counterexample of $g \notin S$   can  u help me

Comment: You can't think of any functions $g$ which don't satisfy both $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) = 0$?

Comment: ok @Mattew  i  take $g(x) = x $

Answer (score 1):

I think your definition of a subring is incorrect. The correct definition is that for all $a,b\in S$,

1. $a-b\in S$
2. $ab\in S$
3. $1_R\in S$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring. Condition $3$ rules out your set as a subring.

Comment: Not every author insists that a ring have a $1$. In fact, your link explicitly mentions this case: "For those who define rings without requiring the existence of a multiplicative identity, a subring of R is just a subset of R that is a ring for the operations of R (this does imply it contains the additive identity of R)."